# How to : terraform snowflake stage credentials and use AWS IAM role arn

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, amazon-iam, terraform0.12+

I am trying to Terraform snowflake_stage and use the arn from the IAM role, that was also terraformed, as the credential.
The Snowflake SQL works when I use:

```
create stage dev
  URL='s3://name_of_bucket/'
  storage_integration = dev_integration
  credentials=(AWS_ROLE='arn:aws:iam:999999999999:role/service-role-name')
  encryption=(TYPE='AWS_SSE_KMS' KMS_KEY_ID='aws/key')
  FILE_FORMAT=DATABASE.PUBLIC.SCHEMA.FORMAT_NAME
  COPY_OPTION=(ON_ERROR='CONTINUE' PURGE='FALSE' RETURN_FAILED_ONLY='TRUE');
```

but when I try to write an equivalent Terraform resource "snowflake_stage" using:

```
resource "snowflake_stage" "stage" {
  name = "dev"
  url  = "s3://name_of_bucket/"
  storage_integration = "dev_integration"
  schema = "public"
  credentials = "AWS_ROLE='aws_iam_role.snowflake_stage.arn'"
  encryption = "(TYPE='AWS_SSE_KMS' KMS_KEY_ID='aws/key')
  file_format = "DATABASE.PUBLIC.SCHEMA.FORMAT_NAME"
  copy_options = "(ON_ERROR='CONTINUE' PURGE='FALSE' RETURN_FAILED_ONLY='TRUE')"
}
```

I get :
SQL compilation error: invalid value [Not a property list: TOK_LIST] for parameter '{1}

The value on the encryption seems to need the "AWS_ROLE='..'" to be valid.

I've tried just using :

```
credentials = aws_iam_role.snowflake_stage.arn
```

but got a different set of errors.

How do I combine the :

```
credentials = "AWS_ROLE='
```

with the
aws_iam_role.snowflake_stage.arn
then append the :

```
`)"
```

for the credentials value  ?

Comment: I have also tried:  credentials = "AWS_ROLE='${aws_iam_role.snowflake_stage.arn}'"   and credentials = "(AWS_ROLE='${aws_iam_role.snowflake_stage.arn}')"    with the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you are missing closing `"` in `encryption`. It should be:

```
encryption = "(TYPE='AWS_SSE_KMS' KMS_KEY_ID='aws/key')"
```

Second, for the role:

```
credentials = "AWS_ROLE='${aws_iam_role.snowflake_stage.arn}'"
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit late on this, but encryption should be:

```
encryption = "TYPE='AWS_SSE_KMS' KMS_KEY_ID='aws/key'"
```

rather than:

```
encryption = "(TYPE='AWS_SSE_KMS' KMS_KEY_ID='aws/key')"
```

Moreover using storage integration on it's own will be fine as long as you configure it with the appropriate role and permission on the role ( S3, KMS, and STS policy document)
Then you can get rid of encryption and credentials field.